# How to play video on an ios captive portal pop up browser

Tags: ios, browser, wifi, mobile-safari, captivenetwork

I've setup a Captive Portal with dd-wrt, wifidog, authpuppy and some plugins from authpuppy as well as my own web app.

I've found that video tag from html 5 could not be played on ios popup broswer(I think it's a UIWebView), while android works fine.

Is it possible to make video play-able on this reduced version browser from ios?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It works in ios 7.

It seems that ios 6 (or below) cannot load some resource types (such as mp4 or zip and so on) in the popup web browser.

[Here](http://blog.tanaza.com/blog/bid/318805/iOS-7-and-captive-portal-a-guide-to-captive-portal-requirements) mention a method to how to solve these kind of problems.(it skips the popup browser)

But if you really want to play videos in the popup browser, I'm also researching it...:P

Comment: Did your research bring any new information on this topic? It would be nice if you would share them with us. Seems like in iOS 8 this isn't working too.